# AForge FFT2 and matlab FFT2 results dont match

Tags: c#, matlab, fft

I tried using [Aforge.Math](https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET) for doing FFT2 on 2D complex matrix and tried the same on matlab

On C#, for AForge:

```
Complex[,] array2D = new Complex[,] { {  (Complex)1,  (Complex)2 }, {  (Complex)3,  (Complex)4 }, {  (Complex)5, (Complex) 6 }, {  (Complex)7,  (Complex)8 } };
FourierTransform.FFT2(array2D,FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);
```

On Mathlab:

```
x =[1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
fft2(x)
```

but unfortunately the results are not the same
for c#:
[image]

for mathlab:

```
  36.0000 + 0.0000i  -4.0000 + 0.0000i
  -8.0000 + 8.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -8.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -8.0000 - 8.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
```

I have no clue why the results are different, btw I can just use tools , don't know details about FFT2.
Update: AForge result is scaled according to the input matrix size!

Comment: Your AForge does not look correct.  A "Complex" consists of a real and an imaginary.  So (Complex)1 only contains one value instead of two.

Comment: @jdweng(Complex)1 does the casting as a result contains both imaginary and real value

Comment: Your array is wrong.  You are getting two complex numbers instead of one.  See : http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/a4bea38d-b9fb-4a29-bc5f-e79ee55039e0.htm

Comment: @jdweng (Complex)1 means new Complex(1,0).. its the same thing..

Comment: NO, NO, NO!!! { {  (Complex)(1,0),  (Complex)(2,0) }, {  (Complex)(3,0),  (Complex)(4,0) }, {  (Complex)(5,0), (Complex) (6,0) }, {  (Complex)(7,0),  (Complex)(8,0) } };

Comment: @jdweng Vs does not accept your statemenet. it says 'Complex' is a type but is being used as a variable!

Comment: I just want to point out you were creating two complex number instead of one.  Are you adding library Aforge.Math.dll to project and adding namespace Aforge.Math?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161978/discussion-between-md-sifatul-islam-and-jdweng).

Comment: @jdweng No. You are wrong. Asker is correct. `(Complex)1` is `1 + 0i`.

Comment: David : Look at working Matlab code : x =[1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]  it is 1 +2i

Comment: @jdweng No it is not. In the C# code `(Complex)1` is `1 + 0i`. In the Matlab code `1` is, well, `1`. Your pride is once again causing you problems. In both sets of code the input data has size 4x2 and each element of those arrays has zero imaginary part.

Comment: @jdweng if you put  x =[1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8] in console you will see matrix of real numbers, not of complex numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same result as in matlab, change direction to `Backward`:

```
FourierTransform.FFT2(array2D,FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);
```

Comment: it does not give the same output... try it for yourself!

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam I actually tried before posting answer and it gives exactly the same output as matlab from your question.

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam if it still doesn't produce correct output for you - please post screenshot\result of what it produces then.

Comment: I already showed screenshot for 'forward'.... and why would I change direction to backward when I need to match FFT2 forward result with matlab?

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam Because backwards produces output you expect? Not sure what else I can add

Comment: 12 yes it does produce my result... but why? :o
Is not backward means inverse fft?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161977/discussion-between-md-sifatul-islam-and-evk).